# In WatchKit, calling presentControllerWithName from a Modal view anchors the presenting view as root

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have an `WKInterfaceController` containing a `WKInterfaceTable` which calls the

`- (void)presentControllerWithNames:(NSArray *)names contexts:(NSArray *)contexts`

to present 2 paged controllers modally.  If I call

`- (void)presentControllerWithName:(NSString *)name context:(id)context`

from one of those controllers, or more specifically

`- (void)presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:(NSArray *)suggestions
                    allowedInputMode:(WKTextInputMode)inputMode
                    completion:(void (^)(NSArray* results))completion`

and then dismiss the newly presented controller, I loose the **Cancel** button on the presenting modal controller.  So I have no way of getting back to the root controller.

Comment: You're availing some suggestions in the textInput?

Comment: Yes.  Whether I dismiss with cancel or by suggestions the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand, but I believe the root cause of the issue you are having is that you are presenting a modal interface controller on top of another modal interface controller which is not what you want to do. You will run into issues like you are seeing such as `Cancel` buttons not appearing.

Instead, I would encourage you to think outside the box. Instead of presenting a modal on top of another modal, what if you switched page sets using the `WKInterfaceController` [reloadRootControllersWithNames(_:contexts:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:). Then you would no longer have your modal on top of a modal problem.

In summary, navigation design in Watch Apps is a bit tricky, but can generally work out well if you follow the common rules.

- Only use a hierarchical or page based layout system
- Don't present modals on top of modals

Hopefully this helps shed some light.

Comment: Hi @Misha, did the end up solving your issue? If yes, would you mind upvoting and marking as the answer?

Comment: Sadly this is an issue. If this behaviour is not meant to be possible, then Apple should not allow it. In my opinion this is a bug.